# Hash mismatch (integrity check failed) with Azure Blob Storage

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm following http://willi.am/blog/2014/07/03/azure-blob-storage-and-node-downloading-blobs/.

However despite the exact same code, when I download blobs Azure gives the error:

[Error: Hash mismatch (integrity check failed), Expected value is ...]

The line being run is  blobService.getBlobToText, with blobService being the connection to Azure (createBlobService...)

What's going on? :S

My code's below:

```
    // Azure test
    function downloadImageAsText(blobService, containerName, blobName) {

         blobService.getBlobToText(
              containerName,
              blobName,
              function(err, blobContent, blob) {
                  if (err) {
                      console.error("Couldn't download blob %s", blobName);
                      console.error(err);
                  } else {
                      console.log("Sucessfully downloaded blob %s", blobName);
                      console.log(blobContent);
                  }
              });

    }

    function uploadImage(blobService, containerName, blobName, fileName) {

      blobService.getBlobProperties(
        containerName,
        blobName,
        function(err, properties, status) {
            if (status.isSuccessful) {
                // Blob exists
            } else {
                blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(
                    containerName,
                    blobName,
                    fileName,
                    function(error, result, response){
                        if(error){
                            console.log("Couldn't upload file %s", fileName);
                            console.error(error);
                        } else {
                            console.log('File %s uploaded successfully', fileName);
                            downloadImageAsText(blobService, containerName, blobName);
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
    }


    function testAzure() {

      accountName / hash = my details

      var storage = require('azure-storage');
      var blobService = storage.createBlobService(accountName, hash);
      var containerName = 'tst';
      var blobName = 'test.png';
      var fileName = 'test.png';

      blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(containerName, function(err, result, response) {
          if (err) {
              console.log("Couldn't create container %s", containerName);
              console.error(err);
          } else {
              if (result) {
                  console.log('Container %s created', containerName);
                  uploadImage(blobService, containerName, blobName, fileName);
              } else {
                  console.log('Container %s already exists', containerName);
                  uploadImage(blobService, containerName, blobName, fileName);
              }
          }
      });
    }

    function startServer() {
      http = require('http');
      const PORT = 8080;
      var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
      server.on('listening',function(){
        console.log("Server listening on: http://178.62.117.207:%s", PORT);
      });
      server.listen(PORT);
    }

    startServer();
    testAzure();
```

Answer (score 6):

In case someone else runs into this; happens when you store a `Buffer` object but retrieve a `string`.

Comment: Any idea what to do with this?

Comment: @K48 IIRC, you store a `Buffer` in the blob, but then use `getBlobToText` to retrieve that data as a `String`. For some reason the hash calculation differs between the two types and so the operation fails.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following (modifying the code from the blog post you mentioned):

```
var blobName = 'my-awesome-text-blob';
blobService.getBlobToText(
    containerName,
    blobName, {'disableContentMD5Validation': true },
    function(err, blobContent, blob) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Couldn't download blob %s", blobName);
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Sucessfully downloaded blob %s", blobName);
            console.log(blobContent);
        }
    });
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Now getting the error:
Error: An incorrect number of bytes was read from the connection. The connection may have been closed..

Comment: I think this error comes when there's a content length mismatch. Does your document contains accent characters? Could this be related to your problem: https://github.com/azure-contrib/node-azure-search/issues/4?

Comment: Hmm... not sure. It's an image file, test.png, and I want to get the contents so I can send it in a GET request - maybe the characters representing the image data are throwing Azure off?

Comment: If it's an image, then why are you downloading as text? Better function would be `getBlobToStream`: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L1659 IMHO.

Comment: Or alternatively, if you need to use text when uploading the image convert it into base64 encoded string and upload that instead of binary data.

Comment: Thanks for all the help - going to try using getBlobToStream and doing that then. Still seems weird the toText function isn't working, either it's broken and Microsoft need to fix it, or they need better error handling, since the errors I'm being given are practically useless. :P

Answer (score 1):

It can happen because of many internal MD5 check failures which works differently when you use HTTPS. Can you please try specifying your storage account as https? Like -

var blobService = storage.createBlobServiceAnonymous('https://MyAccountXX.blob.core.windows.net/');

Otherwise for me, this download function is working fine.

For reference, you can try following actual documentation - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/

Comment: In the documentation however, they download blobs to the server. That works for me too - what isn't working is the getBlobToText, which is mentioned but not demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

When you store a Buffer object, you can retrieve it with getBlobToStream.

```
const data: Buffer[] = [];
const stream = new PassThrough();

stream.on('data', (d: Buffer) => {
    data.push(d);
});

this.blobStorageContext.service.getBlobToStream(
    this.blobStorageContext.getContainerName(),
     blobName, stream, (error) => {
         if (error) {
           console.log(error);
         } else { 
           console.log(Buffer.concat(data));
         }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently ran into this problem myself. Somehow npm -install azure-storage -g helped it. It might be that the package is updated on the npm and md5 calculation has changed since. Once I updated the azure-storage package, everything works like a charm.